# How do I score a specific query over a specific Document?

Tags: lucene

In Lucene 5.4, I Have a *Document* and a *Query* object and I want to score this query for this document using some simillarity function (i.e. BM25).

How can I do this? The way I got the job done was looping over all results of a search and comparing documents with the document I want to evaluate.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is clear what you're asking. It seem that what you want may be achievable through your own BM25 `org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer`. Or maybe your should try writing your own `org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get scoring details for a particular document for a given query, you want to use [`IndexSearcher.explain()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int)).  This provides a lot of useful details about how the scoring algorithm operates.  You can get the final score from the Explanation with [`Explanation.getValue()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Explanation.html) (at the root node, if you start navigating through with getDetails, those sub-nodes won't return the same value):

```java
IndexSearcher searcher  = new IndexSearcher(reader);
//Make sure you set the Similarity to the correct algorithm
searcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
Explanation explain = searcher.explain(myQuery, myDocID);
float score = explain.getValue();
```

Comment: IndexSearcher will return several documents. I want to score one single document against one specific query.

Comment: @VitorAlcântaraBatista - I'm sorry, it seems I misunderstood your question.  I've rewritten my answer, I believe it should address your question better now.